# pokemon go locked me out of my account and i can't log in!

Tags: pokemon-go

so I got the new update, and when I went into the game, professor willow came up like when I started playing. I tried to login with google but it didn't work, and now when I try to log in, the choice to log in with google won't even come up anymore!

Comment: There's at least three different issues going on here, from what I can see.  You need to clarify what it is you're needing help with.

Answer (score -1):

First of all try reinstalling, if this keeps happening I suggest contacting Niantic here's a link - https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us